# Is it inauspicious to cut Amla tree?

Tags: vishnu

We are having Amla tree in our house that is 10 years old. We are worried as it grows old, it could damage the foundation of our house. The tree is just 3-4 feet distance.

But I have heard Amla tree is auspicious as per hinduism. So we are worried about cutting it. Anyone who can throw more light about the auspiciousness of Amla tree, and is there any harm in cutting it can share some info

Answer (score 1):

#### Barring extraordinary circumstances viz. the āpaddharma (आपद्धर्म), it might not be a very good idea to harm the Amla tree, or any tree in general.

[Padma-Purana 7.24](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365865.html)

> अशुभं वाशुभं वापि यत्कर्मामलकीतले ।
> क्रियते मानवैर्विंप्र भवेत्तत्सत्यमक्षयम् ॥ ७.२४.५० ॥
>
> > 50. That act, auspicious or inauspicious, which is done by men at the root
> >     of āmalakī, would certainly become inexhaustible, O brāhmaṇa.

Cutting a tree unnecessarily is a 'bad-deed'. So such bad deeds will amplify in specific case of cutting the Amla tree.

Further,

> धात्रीतरुं च यो हंति सर्वदेवगणाश्रयम्
> स ददाति हरेरंगे घातं नास्त्यत्र संशयः ॥ ६५ ॥
> सर्वदेवमयी धात्री विशेषात्केशवप्रिया
> सम्यग्वक्तुं गुणं तस्या ब्रह्मणापि न शक्यते ॥ ६६ ॥
> धात्र्यास्तुलस्या विदधाति भक्तिं यो मानवो ज्ञातसमस्ततत्वः
>
> > **There is no doubt that he who harms the dhātri tree, the resort of all
> > gods, gives blows on the body of Viṣṇu.** Dhātrī is full of all gods. It
> > is especially dear to Viṣṇu. Even Brahmā cannot correctly describe its
> > virtues.

(*Dhātrī (धात्री) is another name for 'Amla' or the Indian gooseberry.*)

##### So, Padma-Purāṇa forbids harming the Amla tree.

Further, several Purāṇas forbids cutting trees in general.

For instance - Agni Purāṇa

> हृद्द्रुमच्छिद्वज्रशस्त्रके ॥ २०३.०१६ ॥
>
> > 16. One who cuts a tree (would be put) in (the hell) vajraśastraka. ([Chapter 203](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083432.html))

---

In the case cited in the question, maybe cutting be allowed under the āpaddharma circumstances. Otherwise, scriptural view in general, is against any kind of unnecessary deforestation.